# Something wrong with my Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Ruby on Rails and the Devise gem.

At first, everything was fine. The views are like the below, and I have failure flash.

[image]

But, I don't know how, someday, the Devise is not working right. The views turn out to be ugly and no more failure flash. Like below.
[image]

Does anybody knows how. I don't change the files in app/views/devise. Thank you!

Comment: Did you add any css library. Bootstrap or Zurb etc gems?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap. And recently I updated my bootstrap from 2.0 to the newest 3.1

Comment: Thats what is causing this. Bootstrap styles are getting applied to your HTML elements. Its not something that Devise is doing.

Comment: The first screenshot is the plain HTML without bootstrap and second one is with bootstrap css.

Comment: Oh, then why the failure flash is missing? how can I turn it back to what it was like?

Comment: If sign_in fails then Devise sends flash alerts, you need to take care of that in application.html.erb. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Devise` has not stopped working.
The views look different because you have added `Bootstrap` to your application.

The first screenshot is with plain HTML without any css and second screenshot is with `Bootstrap` css applied on the pure HTML elements.

As for the flash messages:

Make sure that you have following code in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you add some gems, like

```
bootstrap-rails
foundation-rails
```

they may affect your original css style, try to disable them and try again.